# Installing GCC on Windows

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc, cygwin

I'm trying to set up the `GCC` to be able to compile `C/C++`.
I have the newest version of Eclipse and have already installed the CDT plugin. Afterwards I installed `Cygwin`, I'm also using Windows.
But when I create a new `C` project and build and run an example code, it says

> Launch failed. Binary not found.

Additionally I set the following options:

**Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->**

**Environment**

- Path: `C:\cygwin64\bin`

**Settings**

- `Cygwin PE Parser` and `PE Windows Parser` are activated

**Tool Chain Editor**

- Current Toolchain: `Cygwin GCC`

But it all didn't fix my problem.
It is important, that my code can also be run on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to start eclipse from within a cygwin shell, to let it find the GCC toolchain.
An often better choice for windows is to use MinGW, that provides better native executables than cygwin.

Another option I'm using on my windows laptop, is running Eclipse and GCC in a vmware linux installation. If it's primarily important your code runs on linux, this would be the way to go. If your code should run on both OSs, MinGW is the right choice IMHO.

BTW: Cygwin is not Windows. It's a unix emulation running besides a windows OS.

Comment: How can I start Eclipse from the cygwin shell? Would I only have to do it once?

Comment: No you have to start it everytime from shell. Just lookup the directory where you installed eclipse, put this to your PATH variable or give the full path as prefix and execute `eclipse`. You shouldn't insist on cygwin, MinGW GCC is much easier.

Comment: I heard that cygwin is more linux related. Would my code also be runnable on Linux if I use MinGW?

Comment: If you keep it portable yes. Just don't use any windows specific stuff. BTW, it's not your code running, but the compiled and linked executable. The latter can't be put on a linux system to run there anyway. To do this you need to cross-compile.

Comment: So if I upload just the code at my university, I don't have to bother, on which OS the prof. checks it?

Comment: Again, if you keep it portable yes. But for your situation and if you know your prof will check on a linux system, I'd prefer to develop it on a linux system as well (there might be subtle differences sometimes). Run linux from a VMWare image then, this works very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/

You install it then use an editor in Windows that points to the compiler.

E.g. in codeblocks go to
settings -> compiler -> toolchain executables (with GNU GCC Compiler selected in the 'selected compiler') -> try auto-detect. If not, point it to C:\TDM-GCC-32

Then, inside TDM-GCC-32\bin
use the following:

Compiler: gcc.exe

C++ Compiler: g++.exe

Link for dynamic libs: g++.exe

linked for static libs ar.exe